# How to run qemu with a Yocto generated image on a distant machine?

Tags: qemu, yocto

I am using an ubuntu on a distant machine and I'd like to use the `runqemu` command to start the image. I think there's a way to redirect the serial to the actual one `pts/0` or `pts/1`, but I didn't manage to do it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet so add here.

Why don't use ssh to log in the remote ubuntu and run runqemu with option nographic?

Comment: Didn't see this option ... Thanks